# Json Post causes Error 422

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, devise, android-volley

I am using devise for login from an android app, but getting an error 422 when trying to login. i am using volley to post the json to the rails server,
here is the code of the session controller

```
def create
  self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
  set_flash_message(:notice, :signed_in) if is_flashing_format?
  sign_in(resource_name, resource)
  yield resource if block_given?
  respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_in_path_for(resource) do            |format|
    format.json {render :json => {:success => true} } # this code will get executed for json request
  end
end
```

and this is my login request in the android

```
    public LoginRequest(String email, String password, Response.Listener<String> listener){

    super(Method.POST, LOGIN_REQUEST_URL, listener, null);
    params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("email", email);
    params.put("password", password);

    new Response.ErrorListener(){

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError){

            try{
                String responseBody = new String(volleyError.networkResponse.data, "utf-8");
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(responseBody);

            }catch (JSONException e){

            }catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e){

            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: May be you need to add content type?

Comment: you mean something like this 'application/json' @Konstantin

Comment: yes, I mean something like this. I think the problem in you server code, not in android.

Comment: to add
 
'config.http_authenticatable_on_xhr = false
config.navigational_formats = ["*/*", :html, :json]' to devise.rb, is it the correct way?

Comment: sorry but I don't know rails code.